# Adding a Scrollbar in a Frame Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am pretty new to GUI in TK and I have the following problem when trying to create frames with a scrollbar:

The page is not shown properly.

This is my code (Updated runnable version):

I have imports, I initialise the root, then I define a starting page witch makes you access the app as a viewer user or authenticate to access all the functionality

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

from scrollbar import VerticalScrolledFrame
    
    
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("DbmApp")
root.geometry("1600x1200")
root.minsize(800, 600)
root.maxsize(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())

def main():
    paginaIniziale()



#################               PAGINE              #################
def paginaIniziale():
    def vai_menu_Utente():
        conn = db.Connect()
        index.destroy()
        paginaMenuUtente(conn)

    def vai_login():
        index.destroy()
        paginaLogin()

    frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    index = frame.interior
    
    stripe = tk.Label(
        index, text="", font=("Bold", 25), bg="light blue", height=350, width=600
    )
    stripe.place(x=0, y=0)

    background = tk.Label(
        index, text="", font=("Bold", 25), bg="#4876FF", height=5, width=600
    )
    background.place(x=0, y=0)

    stringaUtente = tk.Label(
        index, text="Fratm", font=("Bold", 25)
    )
    stringaUtente.place(x=100, y=50)
    stringaUtente = tk.Label(index, text="Benvenuto nel Database", font=("Bold", 25))
    stringaUtente.place(x=100, y=100)
    stringaUtente = tk.Label(
        index, text="Software by RandomGuy", font=("Consolas", 12), bg="light blue"
    )
    stringaUtente.place(x=450, y=550)

    goToMenuButton = tk.Button(
        index,
        text="Entra come ospite",
        font=("Bold", 15),
        bg="white",
        fg="black",
        command=vai_menu_Utente,
    )
    goToMenuButton.place(x=100, y=250, height=75, width=350)

    goToLoginButton = tk.Button(
        index,
        text="Accedi",
        font=("Bold", 15),
        bg="white",
        fg="black",
        command=vai_login,
    )
    goToLoginButton.place(x=100, y=400, height=75, width=350)

    frame.pack(padx=0, pady=100)
    frame.pack_propagate(False)
    frame.configure(height=600, width=600)

main()
root.mainloop()
```

In this second file I'm creating a class to create Frames with a scrollbar

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *


class VerticalScrolledFrame (ttk.Frame) :
    
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)
        
        # Create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it. 
        vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas (self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                width = 200, height = 300,
                                yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE) 
        vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        
        # Create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it.
        self.interior = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.interior.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_interior)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)
        self.interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor=NW)


    def _configure_interior (self, event):
        # Update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame. 
        size = (self.interior.winfo_reqwidth(), self.interior.winfo_reqheight()) 
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, size[0], size[1]))
        if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
            # Update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame. 
            self.canvas.config(width = self.interior.winfo_reqwidth())

    def _configure_canvas(self, event):
        try:
            canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
            canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas_width:
                # Update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas.
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.interior_id, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        except tk.TclError as e:
            print(f"Error in _configure_canvas: {e}")
```

Comment: You need to call `.pack()` on the scrollbars *before* the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have tried to pack first the scrollbars.                            `.        canvas = tk.Canvas(self) v_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=canvas.yview)
        v_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=v_scrollbar.set)`.                                         Then pack the canvas.                                                       `canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)`. 
But the problem still persist...

Comment: This code does not work, please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to call layout function on `index`.

Comment: I have provided my updated version of the Class done by following a tutorial plus the main, now it should be runnable even if not complete

Comment: Since you have used `.place()` to put widgets into the interior frame, so the interior frame will not be resized.  And you did not specify the size of the interior frame, so it will be 1x1 by default and then only its width will be resized to the same as the canvas when the canvas is resized.  Therefore you cannot see those widget inside the interior frame because its height is still one.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 I updated my code accordingly and now it shows the page properly but it seems like the scrollbar still isn't working

Comment: You set the height of the interior frame to the same as that of the canvas, so the scrollbar will not be activated.  The scrollbar will only be activated when the `scrollregion` is taller than the canvas.

Comment: Did you try to print out `size` inside `_configure_interior()`? If you did, you will find out that it is `(1, 1)`, so the `scrollregion` will set to `(0, 0, 1, 1)`.  This is why the scrollbar not activated.

Comment: @acw1668 No but I replaced the place with pack method and now the scrollbar is working as expected, thanks